Is there a way to have an Azure SQL DB backup the backup file to a different region
Say I have a VM or SQL DB in UAE North , I want the backup file to go to UAE Central and I can restore to both regions. I need to understand how this can be implemented for other Azure services like the SQL DB, logic apps, storage accounts redis and so on.
I am not looking for cross region restore as a solution, even though I will use it, I need the backup file to be stored on a different region
which all resorces have this vackup capability
I was not able to find a way to have the backup to another region
